# Can I send a whisper (shh) message to an Ethereum address?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, whisper

It seems that we can only send a message by creating new symmetric keys and key pairs ( `shh.newSymKey()` and `shh.newKeyPair()`

Then post `shh.post()` a message using the parameters:

- `symKeyId` which encrypts using the symmetric key.
- `sig` optional key pair ID which signs the message

Are Ethereum addresses disconnected from Whisper in term of identity management? It would have been great if we could address a message encrypted with and to an Ethereum address.

I want to do this PoC:

- user (with eth address) `X` wants a secret key that only the users listed on a smart contract have, let usersListed be `A,B,C,X`
- user `X` broadcast using whisper to users `A,B,C` -  "I want the secret key" (this message is encrypted for each user)
- Anybody (`A B or C`) from the list, once this message has been received, send back an encrypted message containing the secret key, to user `X`.

Answer (score -1):

Ethereum keys are used to sign messages.
It is bad practice to use the same key to sign and to encrypt,
as signing and decrypting are the same operation.

Comment: So one solution is to have a smart contract and update it with a whisper identity generated for the smart contract dApp.